# working with symbolic link before the controller/method in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, symlink

i just needed some help i think its about time to ask some good felas for help.
here's my situation, i've been trying to use a symbolic link to fake my url just like this.

```
www.website.com/uk/controllers/method/etc
www.website.com/us/controllers/method/etc
```

aparently codeigniter failes to read the controller. the uk and us segment is a symlink to root directory so I expect it should point that to root. what made me sure that it points to the root is by viewing www.website.com/uk/ it works fine no erros all good. please help me on how to fix this. it might be i'm missing something like in htaccess or in route file.  i've been having a headache about this for a day.

here's my current htaccess contents

```
Options FollowSymLinks


RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.(php|html)
RewriteRule (.*)index\.(php|html)(.*)$ $1$3 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: You question isn't very clear. Can you try explaining a bit more what you want.

Comment: soz if the question is not clear. anyway what i expected to be the result is, normally the flow of uri goes like this "www.website.com/controllers/method/etc"  for some reason i needed to insert uk/us right after the base url, say www.website.com/uk/controllers/method/etc. uk/us are symbolic links which i expected to point out to the base url so nothing more changes need in my other codes. but the codeigniter failed to read my controller it returns 404. any idea?

Comment: ok can you post your latest .htaccess in your question.

Comment: @anubhava question updated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help but if you are using language class, then have a look at this extention:
https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/URI-Language-Identifier

Comment: i was thinking working around the route file is much more safer. almost there but im not upto the language support actually. though same idea as like that. say i have different products to show with different regions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for redirecting `/us/` and `/uk/` to root:

Options FollowSymLinks

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.(php|html)
RewriteRule (.*)index\.(php|html)(.*)$ $1$3 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(system|application)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(?:us|uk)/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: im not sure but i think codeigniter is reading the uk and us as the controller that's why it gives me 404 since theres no controllers exist like those. but whats weird is if i visit www.website.com/uk/ it seems works fine. so i was thinking theres something has to do with the htaccess or the route file. which i dont have any idea

Comment: wait, i descovered something. accessing url www.website.com/uk/controller/method/etc/   redirects me to www.website.com/controller/method/etc. having / at the end of the url redirects me to the real page. does the symlink really works like that?

Comment: Oh that is probably due to your `RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]` which is removing `/` from end. Can you retest by commenting that rule.

Comment: commented that line out.  still having the redirection :(

Comment: But I thought you were getting 404 with `http://www.website.com/uk/controllers/method/etc`. Is this URL changing to `http://www.website.com/controllers/method/etc` in your browser or not?